# Iterating IDs to send in an API call

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of crypto coin IDs that I need to send in an API call to get data against each coin. How do I iterate it and send in API call?

The IDs array being stored:

```
const getIds = async () => {
  Axios.get(
    "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=1&sparkline=false"
  ).then((response) =>
    setCoinIds((coinIds) => [
      ...coinIds,
      ...response.data.map((res) => res.id),
    ])
  );

};
```

The coin details API. The `{coin_id}` is where I need to iterate and send api calls against each ID.

```
export const getCoinsData = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await Axios.get(
      "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/${coin_id)"
    );
    return response.data;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
};
```

In the end, I need to store all coin data in a collective object:

```
const fetchCoinData = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    const fetchedCoinData = await getCoinsData();
    setData(fetchedCoinData);
    setLoading(false);
  };
```

Comment: check if any endpoint for accepting an array of ids exist.

Comment: @Husnain Mehmood Please check my answer considering rate limit of API calls.

Answer (score 0):

Using CoinGecko’s API recursively when on a free version is bit tricky. If you go through this [API documentation](https://www.coingecko.com/en/api/documentation) , you will see a statement saying they have rate limit for their API calls.

`Our Free API* has a rate limit of 50 calls/minute.`

I have rewritten a working code to fetch all coins and get their IDs then recursively call CoinGecko's API for those ids with an interval of 3 sec between each API call, which makes our rate of calling 20 calls/minute.

Here is the code for the same :

Note - You can modify this to fit in with react to set state and all. Currently this can be run with node directly.

```
import axios from "axios";
const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3",
});

const delay = async (ms = 3000) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
};

let coinIds = [];
const getIds = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await instance.get(
            "/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=1&sparkline=false"
        );
        coinIds = [...coinIds, ...response.data.map((coin) => coin.id)];
        console.log(" ~ file: apiCall.js ~ line 14 ~ getIds ~ coinIds", coinIds);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(" ~ file: apiCall.js ~ line 17 ~ getIds ~ e", e.message);
    }
};

const getCoinsData = async (coin_id) => {
    console.log(
        " ~ file: apiCall.js ~ line 22 ~ getCoinsData ~ coin_id",
        coin_id
    );
    try {
        const response = await instance.get(`/coins/${coin_id}`);
        return response.data;
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(
            " ~ file: apiCall.js ~ line 26 ~ getCoinsData ~ e",
            e.message
        );
    }
};

const fetchCoinData = async () => {
    try {
        await getIds();
        coinIds = coinIds.slice(0, 4);
        // uncomment below to call API concurrently (if on paid version)
        // const fetchedCoinData = await Promise.all(coinIds.map((coinId) => getCoinsData(coinId)))

        // if on free version use this
        const fetchedCoinData = await coinIds.reduce(
            (acc, coinId) =>
                acc.then(async () => {
                    await delay();
                    const coinData = await getCoinsData(coinId);
                    return coinData;
                }),
            Promise.resolve()
        );
        console.log(
            " ~ file: apiCall.js ~ line 33 ~ fetchCoinData ~ fetchedCoinData",
            fetchedCoinData
        );
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(
            " ~ file: apiCall.js ~ line 36 ~ fetchCoinData ~ e",
            e.message
        );
    }
};

fetchCoinData();
```